# Using old ciphers in email security

Tags: tls, email, ciphers, rc4

My email provider still supports old `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA` ciphers. What does that mean for me?

If I use an updated system (Ubuntu 16.04) and an updated client (Thunderbird 52), shouldn't it use this ciphers?

But when there is someone with an older system, he would still be able to connect to the server and would not be rejected and send his credentials and content with bad encryption. Is that the unique problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the connection between the MTA and MUA? If so then the the possible attack would be downgrade attacks on the secure channel during the handshake. But as you say, unless you are being actively attacked, the OS/MUA should negotiate at the highest supported cipher suite

Comment: please explain downgrade attacks

Comment: A downgrade attack means an active attacker could, under certain conditions, lower the agreed cipher suite in which the two end points agree on. This is done by making one party think the other party can only support certain cipher suites (such as old poor ones like RC4)

Answer (score 1):

It means that if your client supports RC4 then it may end up using it. Either because the server admin chose to override the client's ciphersuite preference (this was commonly done in response to the "BEAST" attack) or because an attacker has somehow managed to fool the negotiation mechanism (a "downgrade attack").

In general email systems should be regarded as low security. Even if you know what protections are applied to the client connections you usually have no idea what if any protections are being applied to the server to server connections and what level of care the mailserver operators are taking to prevent compromise of data at rest. If you need to send sensitive data by email you should be using end to end encryption.